# Are comparison between macro values bad in embedded programming?

Tags: c++, c, performance, macros, embedded

I am building a program that needs to run on an ARM.
The processor has plenty of resources to run the program, so this question is not directly related to this type of processor, but is related to non powerful ones, where resources and computing power are 'limited'.

To print debug informations (or even to activate portions of code) I am using a header file where I define macros that I set to true or false, like this:

```
#define DEBUG_ADCS_OBC true
```

and in the main program:

```
if (DEBUG_ADCS_OBC == true) {
    printf("O2A ");
    for (j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
        printf("%x ", buffer_obc[jj]);
    }
}
```

Is this a bad habit? Are there better ways to do this?

In addition, will having these IF checks affect performances in a measurable way?

Or is it safe to assume that when the code is compiled the IFs are somehow removed from the flow, as the comparison is made between two values that cannot change?

Comment: You should #ifdef the code instead of an if on the value.

Comment: It is not so much a question of the power of the processor, but the power (optimization ability) of the compiler.

Comment: You have `printf` inside the `if` statement, and you're concerned about performance of the `if`? `printf` takes about a gazillion times as long as the `if`.

Comment: @Borgleader: Many compilers will omit code generation for `if` branches that are always return `false`, but will nonetheless validate syntax.  If one knows that one is using such a compiler, using `if` rather than `#ifdef` within a method may help avoid some nasty gotchas resulting from independent treatment if nested `#ifdef` constructs and nested braces.

Answer (score 7):

Since the expression `DEBUG_ADCS_OBC == true` can be evaluated at compile time, optimizing compilers will figure out that the branch is either always taken or is always bypassed, and eliminate the condition altogether. Therefore, there is zero runtime cost to the expression when you use an optimized compiler.

If you are compiling with all optimization turned off, use conditional compilation instead. This will do the same thing an optimizing compiler does with a constant expression, but at the preprocessor stage. Hence the compiler will not "see" the conditional even with optimization turned off.

**Note 1:** Since `DEBUG_ADCS_OBC` has a meaning of boolean variable, use `DEBUG_ADCS_OBC` without `== true` for a somewhat cleaner look.

**Note 2:** Rather than defining the value in the body of your program, consider passing a value on the command line, for example `-DDEBUG_ADCS_OBC=true`. This lets you change the debug setting without modifying your source code, simply by manipulating the make file or one of its options.

Comment: I agree with note 1. If (older) compiler is using type other than `_Bool` for `bool`, testing for `var == true` is not only redundant, it's dangerous. And it's as useful as writing `var == true == true == true == true`.

Comment: I have to say that for clarity I omitted a detail: the code is actually this
    #define DEBUG_ADCS_OBC True

and True is defined in another header. I'm not using any standard library for the bool values. If this can help.

Answer (score 4):

The code you are using is evaluated everytime when your program reaches this line. Since every change of  DEBUG_ADCS_OBC will require a recompile of your code, you should use #ifdef/#ifndef expressions instead. The advantage of them is, that they are only evaluated once at compile time.

Your code segment could look like the following:

Header:

```
//Remove this line if debugging should be disabled
#define DEBUG_DCS_OBS
```

Source:

```
#ifdef DEBUG_DCS_OBS

printf("O2A ");
for (j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
    printf("%x ", buffer_obc[jj]);
}

#endif
```

Comment: It's only evaluated every time if optimizations have been turned off.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with getting the compiler to do this is the unnecessary run-time test of a constant expression.  An optimising compiler will remove this, but equally it may issue warnings about constant expressions or when the macro is undefined, issue warnings about unreachable code.

It is not a matter of "bad in embedded programming", it bears little merit in any programming  domain.

The following is the more *usual* idiom, will not include unreachable code in the final build and in an appropriately configured a syntax highlighting editor or IDE will generally show you which code sections are active and which are not.

```
#define DEBUG_ADCS_OBC

...

#if defined DEBUG_ADCS_OBC
    printf("O2A ");
    for (j = 0; j < 50; j++) 
    {
        printf("%x ", buffer_obc[jj]);
    }
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll add one thing that didn't see being mentioned.

If optimizations are disabled on debug builds, and even if runtime performance impact is insignificant, code is still included. As a result debug builds are usually bigger than release builds.

If you have very limited memory, you can run into situation where release build fits in the device memory and debug build does not.

For this reason I prefer compile time `#if` over runtime `if`. I can keep the memory usage between debug and release builds closer to each other, and it's easier to keep using the debugger at the end of project.

Answer (score 2):

The optimizer will solve the extra resources problem as mentioned in the other replies, but I want to add another point. From the code readability point of view this code will be repeated a lot of times, so you can consider creating your specific printing macros. Those macros is what should be enclosed by the debug enable or disable macros.

```
#ifdef DEBUG_DCS_OBS
myCustomPrint    //your custom printing code
#else
myCustomPrint    //No code here
#end
```

Also this will decrease the probability of the macro to be forgotten in any file which will cause a real optimization problem.